# is there a way to sync vue data values with global store state values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I want to update my data values with values in the store.js, how it is possible? below code gave me blank page error.

App.vue

```
data() {
    return {
    storeState: store.state,
    Counter: this.storeState.Counter, 
    }
    }
```

store.js

```
   export const store = {
         state: {
         Counter: 1,
         }


     CounterUpdater(value) {
     this.state.Counter = (value);
     },
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to a data property (`storeState`) inside the `data` option that way, and you don't need it anyway.  You should use computeds to sync component values with Vuex values.  Remove both data values:

```js
computed: {
  Counter() {
    return this.$store.state.Counter;
  }
}
```

Or use `mapState`:

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
```

```js
computed: {
  Counter() {
    ...mapState(['Counter'])
  }
}
```

Also make sure your store mutation is inside `mutations` and using the proper syntax:

```js
state: {
  Counter: 1
},
mutations: {
  CounterUpdater(state, value) {
     state.Counter = value;
  }
}
```

It's also recommended to name your variables according to [camelCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Guidelines/Code_guidelines/JavaScript#variable_naming) convention (i.e. means lowercase `counter` in your code)

Comment: I don't use vuex, I use simple global store, could you guide me that way please?

Comment: Why not use Vuex?

Comment: I heard it is for middle to big projects, I only have a few variables

Comment: That's inaccurate, it's for any size project that needs centralized data.